# How does JUnit process the @Before annotation

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I was looking at Java's Reflection feature and got to know about the proxy pattern used for the purpose to write annotation processors. Is there a similar `@Before` class annotation processor written inside [org.junit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/%E2%80%8E) package? I tried finding it but couldn't locate the exact class which does this job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean. The term "[annotation processor](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/)" often refers to a plugin that runs during the compilation phase to generate code based on annotations. In this case, however, the @Before, @After, and @Test annotations can be trivially processed at runtime simply by invoking [Class.getMethods()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()) to retrieve the list of methods on the test class, and then using [Method.getAnnotation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class)) or [Method.getDeclaredAnnotations()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations()) to inspect the annotations on the methods of that class to find the methods with those annotations.

Comment: yeah, that's correct, but which class in JUnit framework is doing that?

Comment: TestClass.getTestMethods() is doing this: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/TestClass.java